# HTML5: Video doesn't load when trying to add subtitles

Tags: html, video

Live example code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/inspiredtolive/5t8fbod2/

I changed the video source in the 2nd video and all of the sudden, the video doesn't even load.

```
<video controls crossorigin="anonymous">
    <source type="video/mp4"  src="http://potatotest.eu.pn/html-practice/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4">
    <track kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English" default src="//releases.flowplayer.org/vtt/subtitles-en.vtt">
</video>
```

Removing the crossorigin attribute will allow the video to load but the subtitles won't show up. It might have something to do with the video source? What do I do?

Comment: What browser you are trying?

Comment: `http://potatotest.eu.pn` doesn't send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. When you make the request with `crossorigin` attribute set to `"anonymous", it will reject the request, thus the "no video found" error.
For the subtitles, I don't have this issue on FF : https://jsfiddle.net/5t8fbod2/1

Comment: @Kaiido Oh weird. Thanks. Any idea on how to get this to work on Chrome? potato.test is actually my domain that I do random stuff on. I'm not entirely sure how to add that header.

Comment: After further tests, it seems that this is an actual bug from Chrome which doesn't accept video's and vtt's domains are different (except for `localhost`).
The solution would then be to just save the vtt on your server

Comment: @Kaiido Doesn't seem to be working still @.@ http://jsfiddle.net/inspiredtolive/5t8fbod2/2/

Comment: Try it from a page on your server, it should work... Definitely I think it's a bug, can't explain what happens though but it worth raising a bug report to webkit bugzilla. Maybe due to the fact that `flowplayer.org` does use `https` protocol...

Answer (score -3):

The `<video>` tag has no `crossorigin` attribute. Remove them both.

Comment: First sentence about [mdn article **CORS settings attribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) : "In HTML5, some HTML elements which provide support for CORS, such as `<img>` or `<video>`, have a crossorigin attribute"

Comment: When I removed those attributes, it worked fine for me.